# How to place automatically a bone/vertex/object or a group of them in the center of the screen and zoom in them

Tags: modeling, objects, add-on, bones, edit-mode

I would like to know if you know how to place `automatically` a bone/vertex/object or a group of them in the center of the screen as soon as I click over it / them with the right mouse button or if there is some addon that already does it. I'm realizing that it would be very useful because the movements that I do to with the mouse wheel are always the same and if a script does them for me,I will save a lot of time. Plus,I would like to zoom in the object,so that I can see it better.

So,What the script should do ? Every time I click with the right mouse button on a bone or a group of bones,automatically it should press the dot and it should zoom in the selected object.

Each time I click on a bone I need to place it on the center of the screen and I need to zoom in. So,why I need to press the dot and the mouse wheel manually each time ? They are extra steps that I don't need.

I imagine that adding the zoom feature is a little more complicated than pressing automatically the dot because it depends about how the objects are big...thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the User Preferences under the tab Input there are all the categories for the key bindings.

If you expand the 3DView category and then the 3DView(Global) category by clicking on the little arrows/triangles you can scroll down to the end of 3DView(Global)'s entries until you see the button Add New.

If you click on this button a new entry "none" is added. If you expand it, again by clicking on its arrow, there will be a field that also says "none". 
In this field you can put the following:

view3d.view_selected

Press return to accept it. On the right the current shortcut is displayed with its default value "A". LeftClick on that so that it says "Press a key" and click the right mouse button. Now you have assigned RightClick to the operator. You can also chose one or several modifier keys with the checkboxes below.

Now if you select something by right clicking on it it should be put in the center of the screen and zoomed in on.
If you like how it works you can go back to your User Preferences and click Save User Settings.

Comment: Hello man. I did as you said,but it does not work. When I click with the right mouse button nothing happens. check here : https://postimg.org/image/nxv7ovnpj/ to see if everything is ok...

Comment: No there is something wrong, try to retype the "view3d.view_selected" into the field. It should look like this: http://imgur.com/PUvL2R2